# Geom_label_repel: How to pull labels toward 4 corners of a scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I have a set of product scores I want to visualise in a scatter.  What I'm trying to do is have the labels pull to the four separate corners of the chart. In reality, I have 30-40 to space which is why I'm using ggrepel for the labels.

```
`
library(ggplot2)

peer_score <- c(3.5, 3.5, 2, 2 )
mkt_score <- c(3.5, 2, 3.5, 2)
revenue <- sample(1:75, 4, replace = T)
prod_name <- c("Product 1", "Product 2", "Product 3", "Product 4") 

df <- data.frame(prod_name, revenue, peer_score, mkt_score)

head(df)

ggplot(df, aes(peer_score, mkt_score)) + 
  geom_point(color = "blue", alpha=0.5) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label=prod_name)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=3, linetype="dashed", alpha = 0.9, colour = "dark grey") +
  geom_hline(yintercept=3, linetype="dashed", alpha = 0.9, colour = "dark grey") +
  xlim(1,5) +
  ylim(1,5)
`
```

So I would want 'Product 1' to be pulled to the top right, 'Product 2' to the bottom right, etc

[image: Scatterplot]

I have tried using nudge_x or nudge_y but that sends labels all in the same direction.  Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure whether that will work for your real case. But at least for your example data one option would be to use e.g. one `geom_label_repel` for each of the four quadrants which would allow to set the nudging and the alignment individually.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
nudge <- .1

ggplot(df, aes(peer_score, mkt_score)) +
  geom_point(color = "blue", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_label_repel(data = subset(df, peer_score < 3 & mkt_score < 3), aes(label = prod_name), nudge_x = -nudge, nudge_y = -nudge, hjust = 1, vjust = 1) +
  geom_label_repel(data = subset(df, peer_score < 3 & !mkt_score < 3), aes(label = prod_name), nudge_x = -nudge, nudge_y = nudge, hjust = 1, vjust = 0) +
  geom_label_repel(data = subset(df, !peer_score < 3 & mkt_score < 3), aes(label = prod_name), nudge_x = nudge, nudge_y = -nudge, hjust = 0, vjust = 1) +
  geom_label_repel(data = subset(df, !peer_score < 3 & !mkt_score < 3), aes(label = prod_name), nudge_x = nudge, nudge_y = nudge, hjust = 0, vjust = 0) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 3, linetype = "dashed", alpha = 0.9, colour = "dark grey") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 3, linetype = "dashed", alpha = 0.9, colour = "dark grey") +
  xlim(1, 5) +
  ylim(1, 5)
```

[image]